# Como Leer archivo en pandas hasta encontrar columna vacia?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hola amigos buenas tardes.
tengo una inquietud de como leer un archivo de excel por medio de pandas y python hasta encontrar una columna vacía.  La situación es la siguiente, debo leer la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy leyendo el archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
pd.read_excel(D:\Ruben\proyecto.xlsx, usecols= 'B:J', skiprows =70,nrows=10)
```

Pero eventualmente, este rango (B:J) se que ira creciendo, y me preguntaba si existe la forma de leer este dataframe hasta encontrar la columna vacía, en este caso la columna vacía es la columna K.

Comment: lee todo el excel

Comment: hola Christian, gracias por responder.  Y gracias por hacerme caer en cuenta que no fui explicito que despues de la columna K, hay otra tabla que no debo tener en cuenta.